# MySQL syntax problem in "SELECT * FROM INTO FILE"

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064, into-outfile

I'm trying to move tables between two databases and I'm using this command that is given by MySQL :

```
SELECT * 
  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt' 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
 FROM test_table;
```

As it is written in the MySQL Dev Manual. I'm using MySQL 5.1.

Error :

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\n'' at line 1)

I'm getting a problem every time I run it. It it says that there is a syntax error becasue of '\n' ? What is the solution to this problem ? I'm using MySQL Workbench to query the database. I tried the command line, IT gives the same error.

Please don't suggest alternatives, I just want this method to work.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?  Could try "SELECT * FROM test_table INTO ...".

Comment: I tested on MySQL 4.1, I get an error about file permissions - no syntax error.  What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I'm using 5.1 ... It should work as noted in its Manual.

Comment: whatever... Have you tried putting the INTO after the FROM?

Comment: Have you not seen my answer below? Your order is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your table reference is out of place, as per the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

`SELECT *
  FROM test_table
  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt' 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'

  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`

Answer (score 0):

replace \n with \ \ n.without spaces. See if that works.